# ldd equivalent which fail when library not found

Tags: dynamic-linking, exit-status

Assume I perform `ldd /bin/ls` with the pthread library removed. I obtain

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc3563000)

libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f87e5459000)
libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f87e5254000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f87e4e92000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f87e4c22000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f87e4a1e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005574bf12e000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f87e4817000)
libpthread.so.0 => not found
```

The return code is zero. Is there a command returning an error in this case? Something similar to

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -z $(ldd ${target} | grep 'not found') ]]; then
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care with `ldd` on linux; it's just a `bash` script which, at least on older systems, will run the given program with `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1` in its environment.

This means that if the program has other interpreter than `/lib{64,32}/ld-*`, that program will be run with your target as its first argument, even if you didn't mean to do it. If you run `ldd` on an executable owned by some other user, that user will own *you* instead.

You can check what interpreter is defined in the ELF headers with `readelf -l "$target" | grep interpreter`.

On newer systems, `ldd` has been changed to pass the target as argument to an interpreter taken from a list of 'good' interpreters (eg. `/lib64/ld-linux.so.2 target`); I don't find that convincing, but it's up to you to make the determination if that's safe enough.

If you find all that acceptable, the simplest way to do it is:

```
if ldd "$target" | grep -q 'not found'; then
   echo >&2 "$target is missing dependencies"
   exit 1
fi
```

If called in 'trace mode' (as from ldd), the default dynamic loader on linux will always exit with a 0 status, and there's no way to change that via command line switches or environment variables; you'll have to change its source code.

Comment: See also [CVE-2009-5064](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16750).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would it take for you to find “that” convincing?

Comment: Nothing -- ld.so is complex enough so that's no safe way to run in 'dry' mode with unknown binaries.  Of course you won't find spectacular exploits against it, because it wasn't a real security issue in the first place, so it's not worth bothering with; no sysadmin worth their two bits would use ldd against random binaries.

Comment: From the `ldd` man page ... safer to use `objdump -p /path/to/program |grep NEEDED` instead.

Comment: @RubberStamp compare the output of `objdump -p /usr/bin/xeyes | grep NEEDED` to `ldd /usr/bin/xeyes`. Shared objects depend on other shared objects.